# Why does a "Dim A = New Long? = New Long?" evaluate to nothing?

Tags: vb.net

Why does `Dim A = New Long? = New Long?` evaluate to Nothing when `Dim A = Nothing = Nothing` evaluates to True?

Just want to know purely out of curiosity.

I would expect that they would both come out as true. If I were to put:

```vb
If New Long? = New Long? then
   Dim foo = "Hello"
End If
```

The inside statement would not be hit. However Nothing = Nothing would hit the statement. I'm guessing it's how the compiler treats nullable longs but would like an in depth explanation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the application for this code and do you have no other option than to implement this? Or is this just a homework-type question?

Comment: It all explained in the first part of [Nothing (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing). It's more clear if you understand the references to the C# language and you have met the classic (*nullable type must have a value*) exception.

Comment: Spell it out as `Dim A As Boolean?` and it will start to make sense.  An expression that uses a nullable that has no value produces a nullable without a value.

Comment: You can test it with `Dim A = New Long?.Equals(New Long?)`, though. The equality comparer provided by specific objects can have a specific meaning for that objects. You may also take a look at [Nullable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1)

Comment: I believe the behavior is consistent with the behavior of `Null` in conditional operators in the VBA family.  Keep in mind that in VB, `Nothing` means "Default for type" so it is most closely equivalent to `default` in C# rather than `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types#propagation for an explaination.

> Propagation
>
> If one or both of the operands of an arithmetic, **comparison**, shift, or type operation is nullable, the result of the operation is also nullable

Now its worth noting that c# took a different approach here

```
new long?() == new long?() => true
```

However you can bypass the language designers choice

```
(New Long?).Equals(New Long?) => True

(New Long?)?.Equals(New Long?) => Nothing
```